# Hooking x64 functions

Tags: windows, winapi, hook, system, low-level

I read a few times that hooking x64 is hard because one has to write at least 12 bytes at the beginning of the hooked function and in this process one often overrides jmp or other important instructions.
But if one wanted to call the regular function couldn't one just write the original bytes back call it and hook it again?

Comment: this will be incorrect - what if another thread call this function while you temporary remove hook ? and not effective - every time remove/restore hook. only way calculate exactly instructions lens and check for jmps (I do this by step tracing). copy this instructions to trampoline with jump back to function body, and replace first bytes for own jmp

Comment: Is there any library that can do this consistently? All libraries I tried failed.

Comment: @JustSomeCoolGuy There are tons of hooking libraries for x64, which ones have you tried exactly, and how have they failed?